# CSS Conditions?

Tags: html, css, conditional-statements, webshop

I'm relatively new to HTML & CSS and hope to find some help here.

I got [this problem](http://screencast.com/t/CfNDVW9gq), so when the link is active it moves to the next menue point.

I need a solution for when a menue point has more characters and gets a second line, for all the categories that do not have a second line, there is no problem when the link is active.

Can you help me out? Is there a way of working with (if-)conditions in CSS formating!?

Thanks in advance,
and sorry for my bad english ;)

**P**

Comment: Post you HTML and CSS preferably in [http://jsfiddle.net/]

Comment: a screenshot is not enough to identify the issue, you should post your code

Comment: sorry guys, I am new to this - thanks for the hint. Will use _jsfiddle_ or _codepen_ next time. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use this:

```
.active{
    height: auto;
}
```

I don't really know what your problem is, because it's just an image.
Can you maybe add a jsfiddle?

Comment: wow - it can be that easy!?...haha. thanks you saved my day.